# Layout (width) issue with bounty dialog

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounty-remarks

Typing a message:

[image]

Typing some more:
[image]

Browser: Firefox 23

Comment: Repro with Firefox 23, no repro with Chrome 28.0.1500.95